# How to correctly call dlsym in C++

Tags: c++, dlsym

I had checked recently my previously-c-converted-to-c++ code with g++ -Wpedantic, and had been fixing most of the problems, when I stumbled against something I cannot handle:

```
typedef int32_t (*myfunc)(uint32_t*, uint16_t*, uint32_t);
myfunc mf = 0;

int main() {
    mf = (myfunc) dlsym(so_lib, "myfunc");
    return 0;
}
```

With -Wpedantic I get this warning:

```
dynamic_link.cpp: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [enabled by default]
mf = (myfunc) dlsym(so_lib, "myfunc");
                                    ^
```

Please help, how can I change my code to satisfy the compiler and prevent this warning?

Comment: You can try the example [in the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym).

Comment: This is a 18-years old defect in C++: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#195 Shameful.

Comment: try `*(void**)(&mf)`.

Comment: you mean loose the typedef here? with mf = (myfunc)(*(void **)(dlsym(so_lib, "myfunc"))); I get the same result.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux this is quite nasty but it works. Thank you all  :)

Comment: Didn't you get the same warning (except with "ISO C" instead of "ISO C++") when compiling as C (with `-pedantic`)?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with gcc 5.1.0 - no warning

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve] - your warning is not reproducible and it is not clear what type `so_lib` has.

Comment: Requires two typecasts `(myfunc)(intptr_t)dlsym(...)`